# HighCharts navigator: how to disable the expand width icon on hover

Tags: highcharts

I'm using highcharts navigator. I don't need rangeSelector, handles, scrollbar enabled. I've some styling for the navigator.

The problem I'm facing is: When I take my mouse on navigator I see a small expand icon as longs as the mousefocus is in the navigator. Is there any way to disable it?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cbhrp4ao/4/. Taking the mouse pointer inside navigator, the expand width icon can be seen.

HighCharts code:

```
Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
      chart: {
        spacingTop: 170,
        spacingBottom: 20,
        type: 'line'
      },

      navigator: {
        enabled: true,
        top: -10,
        height: 50,
        tickAmount: 12,
        maskFill: 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.2)',
        outlineColor: 'transparent',
        handles: {
          enabled: false,
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
          borderColor: 'transparent'
        },
        series: {
          lineColor: 'transparent',
          fillOpacity: 0
        },
        xAxis: {
          labels: {
            style: {
              color: '#000000',
              fontWeight: 'bold',
              fontSize: '14px'
            }
          }
        }
      },

    scrollbar: {
            enabled: false
        },

    rangeSelector: {
       enabled: false
    },

    series: [{
        name: 'USD to EUR',
        data: usdeur
    }]
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to use CSS to overwrite the rule

```
.highcharts-navigator, .highcharts-navigator * {
  cursor : default !important
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/core972/cbhrp4ao/5/)

Comment: The changes are not being reflected. Is there any prerequisite for using styled-mode? I'm on a angular project.

Comment: You can use css in all project, the fiddle isn't in styled mode. Anyway the solution is in CSS, find the right selector for your project and use it.